# Linux: How does user log out work

Tags: linux, gnome, kill, session, signal

I'm new with linux. I've searched about how to safely log out other user and found few solution but I want to know how they work internally. I have few questions:
1. `pkill -KILL -u {username}` Does it just send SIGKILL to every child of init --user? and does it ensure that every child process is safely killed?
2. Can It be done using sending only signals?

**P.S**
I have program which creates init --user for other user, I'm killing using  SIGTERM but sometimes compiz crashes. Thats why I'm interesting how should it work properly.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. `pkill -KILL -u {username}` Does it just send SIGKILL to every child of init --user? and does it ensure that every child process is safely killed?

It sends SIGKILL to all processes owned by the `{username}` account, regardless of their parent. (Note that "init --user" is somewhat distro-specific.)

However, it's about as far from "safe" as you can go. SIGKILL is the brute force approach which ends all processes without letting them properly shut down and clean up; it's the opposite of "safe."

Many terminal-based programs react to SIGHUP as "line hangup". After a few seconds, the remaining ones can be stopped with SIGTERM. *Only then,* if you still have leftovers after both SIGHUP and SIGTERM, should you use SIGKILL as the final approach.

> 2. Can It be done using sending signals?

Possibly – most programs do understand SIGHUP or SIGTERM. But graphical programs might prefer to be stopped by the *session manager*, i.e. by gnome-session, using ICE/XSMP (I don't know how this works exactly). In general, the "safest" approach would be to use the desktop environment's logoff command; for example:

```
gnome-session-quit --logout --force --no-prompt
gnome-session-save --force-logout --silent
qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 -1 -1
qdbus org.razorqt.session /RazorSession logout
mate-session-save --logout
xfce4-session-logout --logout
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But one more question please. What is the difference between gnome-session-quit and using `pkill -KILL - u {username}`

Comment: `gnome-session-quit` sends an IPC message to gnome-session, which first announces the logout using XSMP, then exits, letting the display manager shut down the Xorg server.

Comment: thanks a lot. One more please :D. So sending SIGTERM to init --user can not be related to compiz crash problem?

Comment: and which one is used when linux is normally logging off?